# Access database directly from jsp

Tags: sql, jsp, jdbc

Is it advisable to do all the DB CRUD operations in jsp itself? I feel its better to keep the operations in a Java class itself and forward the results to the jsp so that the jsp remains free from the burden of handling business logic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP should be used for presentation purpose only and that recommendation is not recent. Look at this 2003 [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/servlets-jsp-140445.html) :

> Don't mix business logic with presentation: For advanced applications,
>   and when more code is involved, it's important not to mix business
>   logic with front-end presentation in the same file. Separating
>   business logic from presentation permits changes to either side
>   without affecting the other. However, production JSP code should be
>   limited to front-end presentation.

Of course, thing have evolved and the article might seem a bit outdated but the fundamentals are still true. Many frameworks separating your application in Model View and controller (MVC) exist.

You can have a look at [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) if you want a popular example.

Comment: Yes. I have used both Spring and Struts and it was indeed better than handling everything in jsp. Just now came across a code where everything is mixed in the jsp. Thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed better to move all the business logic away from jsp pages to java classes. Even better is to apply mvc pattern (model view control) or use some frameworks that already apply this pattern (struts2, jsf, spring etc.)

Comment: Yes, even I have the same opinion. But just now came across such a style of coding now. So wanted to clarify. Thank you for the response :)

Comment: @Phoenix obviously..:)